# Tkinter <Return> event on key release

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to make the `<Return>` event call on the key release, instead of press?

If you use `<KeyRelease>`, then `event.char` is blank for any special key, not just return.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can explicitly set a binding on the release of the return key by binding to `<KeyRelease-Return>`.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", self.on_return_release)

    def on_return_release(self, event):
        self.text.insert("end", "boink! ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

If you don't want anything to happen on a *press* of the return key you can remove the default binding, or create your own binding which returns `"break"`

Answer (score 3):

You could check that `event.keysym=='Return'`:

```
class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        master.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.release)
    def release(self,event):
        if event.keysym=='Return':
            print('Return Release')
root=tk.Tk()
app=App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note that if you have autokey repeat, then there will be KeyRelease events even if you do not physically release the key.

---

To turn off autorepeat under Xwindows:

```
import Xlib.display as display
import Xlib.X as X
import Tkinter as tk
import atexit

@atexit.register
def autorepeat():
    d=display.Display()    
    d.change_keyboard_control(auto_repeat_mode=X.AutoRepeatModeOn)
    x=d.get_keyboard_control()    

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        master.bind('<KeyRelease>',self.release)
    def release(self,event):
        if event.keysym=='Return':
            print('Return Release')

d=display.Display()
d.change_keyboard_control(auto_repeat_mode=X.AutoRepeatModeOff)
x=d.get_keyboard_control()
root=tk.Tk()
app=App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for this, do you know if it is possible to disable auto key repeat?