# How to get a value from an entry box and insert it in a text box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text-widget

Hello and good morning to everyone. It seems the Text widget in tkinter doesn't have the "textvariable" attribute like Label, Entry etc, and the alternative approach is the use of "insert" and with a button. But, is there a way to get a value from one entry box and insert(return) it into the Text widget without a button. Thank you

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text_value = StringVar()
value = Entry(root)
value.pack()

text_rep_trans = StringVar()
rep_trans = Text(root)
rep_trans.pack()

def set_label(name, index, mode):
    ret_value = text_value.get()
    if ret_value == '':
        pass
    else:
        rep_trans.insert(END, ret_value)


text_rep_trans.trace('w', set_label)
text_value.trace('w', set_label)
text_rep_trans.set(' ')
text_value.set(' ')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can bind `<Return>` key event on the `Entry` to a callback, then in the callback add the content of the `Entry` into `Text` when user presses `Return` key in the `Entry`.

Comment: But it keeps on duplicating what is entered into the entry box after adding the bind event. Example, if I enter 55, i get 5 55 555

Comment: My suggestion is to use the `Enter` key to trigger an action.  What to be done in the action really depends on your design.

Comment: @billstone09 Read up on [Events and Bindings - Section <Return>](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#events) and [tkinter-return-event-on-key-release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082277)

Answer (score -1):

You can use root.after( , )
Here is a simple code .

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def main():
    global text
    text = e.get()
    l = Label(root , text = text).grid(row = 1 , column = 0)
    root.after(1 , main)
e = Entry(root)
e.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
root.after(1 , main)
text=""
l = Label(root , text = text).grid(row = 1 , column = 0)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I'm trying to use is the Text widget but the Entry widget